Containerized Bun -js backend with express and postgress db both in same docker image is not working properly
I am developing a backend with bun-js with express library and drizzle
I have containerized both backend and database (postgres).
github-repo
but i encounter a problem where the request to the database remains pending.
1.Error Messages - No error message (well that's the problem!)
docker-compose up --watch, Console
What i am suspecting is how i am retrying the database connection
const client = new Client({
  connectionString:process.env.DB_URL!,
});

let retry =2

while (retry > 0){
try {
    await client.connect();
    break;
} catch (error) {
    if(retry < 0){
        process.exit(1)
    }
    retry = retry -1;
    console.log(error)
    console.log('Trying to connect db failed remaining attempts: '+retry + ". Waiting for 2000ms")
    await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,2000))
}
}

export const db = drizzle(client, { schema: { 
    ...users, 
    ...session,
    ...emailVarification,
    ...resetToken
}, logger: true });

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.use(protectionCSRF)
app.use('/api/user',userRoute)
app.get('/hello-world',(req,res)=>{
    return res.status(200).json({
        message:"Hello World!"
    })
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(process.env.DB_URL)
  console.log(`server running on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/api`);
});

Example code for login handler.
export const login = async (
  req: Request<unknown, unknown, { email: string; password: string }>,
  res: Response<Res<{ email: string; name: string; id: string; email_verified: boolean }>>
) => {
  try {

    const validEmail = z.string().parse(req.body.email);
    const validPassword = z.string().parse(req.body.password);

    console.log('inside login 1')

    const user = await db.query.userSchema.findFirst({
      where: eq(userSchema.email, validEmail),
    });

    console.log('inside login 2')

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        isSuccess: false,
        issues: [],
        message: "Invalid email or password",
      });
    }
    const isValidPassword = await password.verify(user.password, validPassword,"argon2d",);

    if (!isValidPassword) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        isSuccess: false,
        issues: [],
        message: "Invalid email or password",
      });
    }

    const session = await lucia.createSession(user.id, { ip_country: "INDIA" });
    const sessionCookie = lucia.createSessionCookie(session.id);

    res.set("Location", "/");
    res.set("Set-Cookie", sessionCookie.serialize());

    return res.status(200).json({
      isSuccess: true,
      message: "User login success",
      result: {
        email: user.email,
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        email_verified: !!user.email_verified,
      },
    });
  } catch (err: any) {
    if (err instanceof ZodError) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        isSuccess: false,
        message: err.message,
        issues: err.issues,
      });
    }

    return res.status(500).json({
      isSuccess: false,
      message: err.message,
      issues: [],
    });
  }
};

As you see its a login handler where with help of email user if fetched and further process is done.
but if i hit this request. only first console.log(inside login 1) is printed but not second and request keeps pending its not resolved. Following are the necessary docs that may help
Dockerfile
FROM oven/bun:1.1.8-alpine as development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

COPY bun.lockb .

RUN bun install

COPY . .

# CMD [ "bun" ,"run", "dev" ]
RUN bun run build

FROM oven/bun:1.1.8-alpine as production

ARG BUN_ENV=production
ENV BUN_ENV=${BUN_ENV}


WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .

COPY bun.lockb .

RUN bun install --production

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "bun" , "run", "dist/index.js" ]

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DB_URL=postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
    container_name: auth_backend
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: bun run dev #over-riding the default RUN bun run build command from docker file
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - db
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./src
          target: /usr/src/app/src
        - action: rebuild
          path: package.json

  db:
    image: postgres:16.3-alpine3.18
    container_name: My_DB
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      # - .:/dev/shm
      - ~/db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - path: .env
        required: true
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
          
volumes:
  db-data:

github-repo
1.Tried changing environment variable 'DB_URL' to postgres://postgres:pass123@localhost:5430/AUTH
which i used previously before containerizing the backend
2.Changin how i connect to the database in src/index.ts
